# Free static web hosting inside the Tor hidden services network

Tags: onion-services, freedom-hosting, web-hosting

Do anyone know of any free (as in no payment, no ads, and no invites needed) web hosting provider inside the onion network currently? Or did everything die with Freedom Hosting?

I don't want anything fancy, static web hosting is fine (as in no PHP or other serverside scripting). Reliability and available storage space is more important.

For the purpose of this question, hosting a server myself is not possible.

I am aware that one also need to announce the website to the world for anyone to know it exists and be able to find it.

Comment: I'd suggest to search [ahmia.fi](https://ahmia.fi/search). This is a indexing site for hidden services. Many sites have a description. When searching for 'hosting' I got several hits. So it might be one there which can help you.

Comment: Thanks. They are basically all down however, services does not seems to be removed from that index. In fact, I found no free ones that worked.

Comment: I use [Sealandhosting.org](http://sealandhosting.org) they accept Bitcoins and don't need any customer details, just an email-address. Products:
VPS, Domains, Socks, Dedicated Server, Tor Hosting Prices are also ok

Comment: There is currently a discussion going on over on the meta site to determine if questions of this sort are on topic or not. Opinions welcome! http://meta.tor.stackexchange.com/questions/238/questions-asking-for-service-recommendations/

Answer (score 2):

Static-host is a [FreeNet](https://freenetproject.org/), take a look. Free, distributed, anonymous.